# Variations of 得 in 好玩得很

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, sentence-structure

I heard this phrase from a TV drama.
好玩得很。

Are these also correct?

好玩得多。

好玩得很多。

喜欢得很。

喜欢得多。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

得很 (very) is for describing a high degree of the adjective. e.g. 鮮牛肉貴**得很** - Fresh beef is **very** expensive

得多 (much more) is for describing a much higher degree of the adjective for one object in comparison to another object. e.g. 鮮牛肉比冰牛肉貴**得多** - Fresh beef is **much more** expensive than frozen beef

- If you mean 'very', then '多' in  '鮮牛肉貴得很多' is nonsensical. The sentence itself is wrong. It has to be '鮮牛肉貴得很'
- If you mean 'much more', First, you need another item for comparison. And second '很' in  '鮮牛肉比冰牛肉貴得很多' would be redundant.

Either 鮮牛肉比冰牛肉貴[得多]  or 鮮牛肉比冰牛肉貴[很多] would be correct, but not 鮮牛肉比冰牛肉貴[得很多]

In your examples, It would be either 足球好玩得很 (football is very fun to play) or 足球比籃球好玩得多 (football is much more fun to play than basketball)